# What after exec() in ls command: Is the parent process printing the output to the console or the child?

Tags: process, fork, ipc, exec

I have a simple doubt on execution of the command `ls`. As per my understanding from the research I have done on the internet, I understood the below points.

1. When we type `ls` command shell interprets that command.
2. Then the shell process forks and creates the  child process and the parent (shell) executes the `wait()` system call, effectively putting itself to sleep until the child exits.
3. Child process inherits all the open file descriptors and the environment.
4. The child process (shell) executes an `exec()` of the `ls` program, causing the `ls` binary being loaded from the disk (filesystem) and being executed in the same process.
5. When the `ls` program runs to completion, it calls `exit()`, and the kernel sends a signal to its parent indicating the child has terminated.

My doubt starts from here onwards, as soon as `ls` finishes its tasks; does it send the result back to the parent process, or does it display the output to the screen?
If it sends the output back to parent, then is it using `pipe()` implicitly?

Comment: *Child process inherits all the open file descriptors and the environment.* Not to mention the PID, the process control group, the ulimits, the umask. The SELinux security context too (I think).

Comment: @amphetamachine, the others yes (though they're not that relevant wrt. printing), but a child process gets a PID of its own (it's the _process_ id, after all). The PID remains the same through `exec()`, though, but that happens within the same child process

Answer (score 2):

`ls` will output what it has to output on its *standard output*. To do that, it calls the `write` system call, something like:

```
 write(1, "file1  file2...\n", 16)
```

(or more likely it calls `libc` functions like `printf` or `fwrite` that eventually do the `write()` system call)

It assumes that the file descriptor `1` (stdout by convention) was already opened and points to something. Actually, `ls` does check whether its file descriptor 1 points to a terminal or something else. If it doesn't point to a terminal, it does instead:

```
 write(1, "file1\nfile2...\n", 15)
```

That is, it writes one file per line when the output doesn't go to a terminal.

When you write:

```
 ls file1 file2
```

`ls`'s file descriptor 1 will point to the same resource as the shell's fd 1 (so for instance, if it was an interactive shell started by `xterm`, that will point to the pseudo-terminal device controlled by xterm). The shell does nothing special, it's inherited upon `fork` and because the `O_CLOEXEC` flag is typically not set of the file descriptor, it is preserved upon `execve`.

If you write:

```
var=$(ls file1 file2)
```

The shell creates a pipe, and assignes the fd 1 of the child process to the writing end of that pipe and reads the other end of the pipe to fill the `var` variable.

It's not magically done upon exit, it's just done as part of the job of the process. It's independant from any other activity of the shell. `ls` is just another process with its `fd` 1 connected to some resource like the terminal while the shell is another process busy doing a `waitpid()`.

What you may find though is that when stdout is not a terminal, `ls` buffers its output and would only call `write()` when enough data (enough being several kilobytes) have been accumulated or it's closing its output or it's exiting. So, in that regard, you'll find the `write` is done upon exiting, but only as part of the `flushing` of buffers that is being done by those I/O libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the parent process waits until the child process ends by calling [`waitpid`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=waitpid&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en). The parent process gets the PID of the process from [`fork`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=fork&sektion=2&apropos=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&locale=).

This means the child never signals the parent process in any way that it exited or what happened. This is done by the system and not the child process.

If you are talking about the output of the program, the parent typically never receives the output of the child process unless it provided fds. This also means that the child process prints the output and **not** the parent process. The parent process just receives information about the state of the process (for more information see the macros in the [`waitpid`](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=waitpid&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=Debian%206.0%20squeeze&format=html&locale=en) manpage)

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking *neither* of parent and child do the actual output to the screen; instead the operating system kernel (specifically the `tty` driver) does the output.
The processes only send the data to a file descriptor.

Also, instead of speculating `strace -f /bin/bash "ls;exit"` clearly shows who is writing what to the file descriptors (BASH seems to optimize "-c ls" by not forking, so I used the ";exit" afterwards), like this (bash uses `clone`, not `fork`):

```text
...
clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f9814b5d9d0) = 30029
Process 30029 attached
[pid 30028] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
[pid 30029] rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [],  <unfinished ...>
...
[pid 30028] wait4(-1,  <unfinished ...>
...
[pid 30029] execve("/usr/bin/ls", ["ls"], [/* 72 vars */]) = 0
...
[pid 30029] write(1, "00708022-PTF-26962\nCASE00280714\n"..., 18500708022-PTF-26962) = 185
...
[pid 30029] exit_group(0)               = ?
[pid 30029] +++ exited with 0 +++
<... wait4 resumed> [{WIFEXITED(s) && WEXITSTATUS(s) == 0}], 0, NULL) = 30029
...
```

So you see that actually PID 30029 (the child) writes out the file names, exits, and then the parent continues (after `wait4`).

Comment: That's `strace -f /bin/bash -c "ls;exit"`  -- add `-c` to get bash to execute a command. Otherwise the argument is taken as a script filename.

Comment: Seems to depend on the version of BASH:  "/usr/bin/ls" is not a script.

Answer (score 0):

If `exec(3)` succeeds, the program which called it is no more. It is replaced by the program `exec`ed. The new program running inherits the environment, in particular the open files, of the original.

Comment: > Could you pls help me in understanding the concept.My question is does the child sends the result back to the parent?who is printing the output of ls command.is it the child process or the shell,which is the parent process in this case.?

Comment: Your shell `fork(3)`s, and the child then `exec(3)`s `ls`. While `ls` runs, it _is_ the child process, which took over the child shell. The child `ls` writes directly to the screen, while the parent process `wait(2)`s for the child to finish before resuming. The first thing the parent does is print the prompt again.

Comment: Thanks for clearing my doubt.If you dont mind shall i ask 1 more doubt,it was in my mind when i started learning pipes.Even the above doubt itself arise in my mind because of that root doubt..Can a pipe() be called implicitly in any case even if we dont use command like this ls | more.What i meant to ask exactly is if i execute a single command say for eg ls and assume that here  child process   sends data back to parent,then it need to use one or other way say pipe.Then does pipe() is called such scenarios  implicitly even if we dont use "|" operator?

Comment: There is no pipe from the child to the parent in this case. Both just happen to write to the same output file (screen). Unless you explicitly ask it to connect processes with `|`, the shell won't do it.

Comment: @vondrand> Fine you cleared all my confusions.Thanks buddy ;-)